# Update VSCode via .deb file

Tags: software-installation, updates, software-center, deb

Today a new version of `vscode` was available, so I went to https://code.visualstudio.com/ and downloaded the `.deb` file. I clicked the downloaded file, it opened in the `Ubuntu Software Center` and I clicked install to update my current version. So far this is a very user friendly process IF the installation would actually work :-)

What actually happened:

If I go to the Software Center after the installation it still shows me the old version of `VSCode`:
[image]

If I click the downloaded `.deb` file again it still shows me that I can install it and NOT launch it, even if the installation was successful (I can check it by opening VSCode from the dock and check the version).

[image]

My questions are:

1. What happened here?
2. Why is Ubuntu not showing me the updated version in the Software Center?
3. Why does Ubuntu still show me that I can install the .deb file even if I have just installed it
4. How can I show this post to Canonical, so they can finally implement a NOT buggy installation/update process?